# Parsing input text to array and sum values

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, textarea

Hello :) I am stuck in my mini-app developing. I have following text, copied from 3rd party web page:

```
Type A    GZ 600    11.09.2021 12:00        OST    9
Type A    GZ 601    11.09.2021 13:20        ADS    1
Type A    GZ 602    11.09.2021 21:35        OCS    1
Type A    GZ 603    11.09.2021 14:50        CSE    10
Type B    GZ 600    11.09.2021 12:00        OST    5
Type B    GZ 601    11.09.2021 13:20        ADS    3
Type B    GZ 602    11.09.2021 21:35        OCS    6
Type B    GZ 603    11.09.2021 14:50        CSE    12
```

I need to parse it to following format:
`$s = 10, $ns = 11, $bs = 26`, like:

```
echo "S:" . $s . " NS:" . $ns . " BS:" . $bs; // Output: S:10 NS:11 BS:26

where:
$fa = array("OCS", "CSE"); is array of codes
$ns is sum of Type A last column numbers, which 5 column 3-letter code is in the array, 
$s is sum of Type A last column numbers, which 5 column 3-letter code is not in the array
$bs is just sum of Type B last column numbers
```

My code now is following:

```
if(!empty($_POST['indata'])){
  $in_data = $_POST['indata'];                // Get POST data
  $fa = array("OCS", "CSE");                  // Make array
  $ns = 0;                                    // Init ns value
  $s = 0;                                  // Init ss value
  foreach(explode("/n",$in_data) as $line){   // Divide text to lines
    $info[] = explode("    ", $line);         // Divide line to values and put them to array 
    print_r($info);  //Show input for test purposes                         
    if(in_array($info[4], $fa)) {             // Check, if 4th array value (code) is in array
      $ns = $ns + $info[5];                   // plus to $ns, if yes
    } else {
      $s = $s + $info[5];                     // plus to $s, if no
    }
    unset($info);                             // clear array for next usage
  }
}
```

But it seems not cutting line into array. It just shows me lines, not dividing to array. I am using Summernote text editor, it sends data as rows.

Comment: You need a lot of comments to explain your code, and I still cannot understand any of it.

Comment: I think the mistake is in `"/n"`. I think you intended to use `"\n"`, a backslash instead of a forward slash?

Comment: KIKO, i get text from textarea, than i wish it would be splitted to lines, and lines to values. And than i`d like to sum up values...

Comment: Just to bring some coding best practices(?) into this: Have you considered taking a more..CSV-ish approach, here? Like, converting those space globs into say tab characters and then using PHP's builtin support for CSV? I could add some example code, but it might be slightly off topic.

Comment: Maybe there is a tab sign? Try to explode `$line` by `"\t"`.

Comment: No, not tab, but 4 spaces. Checked.

Comment: Thing is, the code gives me the print_r() output when I run it locally. So I'm puzzled as to what the problem really is..

Comment: Just tried to change /n to \n - nothing changed. It do not splits to lines..

```Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
Type A    GZ 600    11.09.2021 12:00        OST    9
Type A    GZ 601    11.09.2021 13:20        ADS    1
Type A    GZ 602    11.09.2021 21:35        OCS    1
Type A    GZ 603    11.09.2021 14:50        CSE    10

) )```

Comment: Why you use `$info[]`? You need to access it then as `$info[0][4]`.

Comment: It is the second full day trying to resolve this quest.. I have working excel file to count it, but my task is to make it on web page >.< May be there is some easier way to parse it? Or put rows to MySQL and than count? But to insert it to MySQL i need to parse it as well... I`m lost :(

Comment: Robert, it is 'bugged feature'. Text do not parses to array, thats why. When it will be like:
Array 0 => {data} 1 => {data} ... x => {data} than i will start using $info[x][4]

Comment: Torbjorn, it does not parse text correctly, and i cant get result. I need to sum Type A to 2 ints and Type B to 3rd int. I also receive print_r correctly, but it is not summable

Comment: @Serique Well.. It does. Kind of ;). You need to think about how $info will look in your code though. As others have already said `$info[]=...` causes it to be *2* levels deep, not 1 level as your code is expecting. If you change it to `$info = ...` it should work better. Also you don't really need the unset(), unless you're using $info later in your code.

Comment: So, if it doesn't explode by new line sign `\n`, then you need to check what sign is at the end of line. Maybe it is `\r` or something strange. I would run `ord` function through first x chars to see what code it returns at the end of the first line.

Comment: Tobjorn, you are my hero! Almost works, but it do not sum first row. A huge step forward. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using `$info[] = ...` you get a 2 levels deep array instead of 1 level as your code is expecting. `$info[] = ...` basically means "Add the right hand side to $info as **one** element". So if the right hand side is a string and $info was empty before you'd get `[0 => "my string"]`. If the right hand side was an array you'd get `[0 => [0 => "my", 1 => "array"]]`.

Do you see what I am getting at? Your code is adding **one** element to $info, never more than that. So to access anything in $info the first part needs to be $info[0]. But the code looks for the 4th and 5th elements, and they'll never be there. On the other hand, if you'd look for the 4th element **inside** the 1st one.. That is, `$info[0]` for the 1st element, and then the 4th inside it: `$info[0][4]`, then you get what you're looking for.

```
if(!empty($_POST['indata'])){
  $in_data = $_POST['indata'];                // Get POST data
  $fa = array("OCS", "CSE");                  // Make array
  $ns = 0;                                    // Init ns value
  $s = 0;                                  // Init ss value
  foreach(explode("\n",$in_data) as $line){   // Divide text to lines
    $info[] = explode("    ", $line);         // Divide line to values and put them to array 
    if(in_array($info[0][4], $fa)) {             // Check, if 4th array value (code) is in array
      $ns = $ns + (int) $info[0][5];                   // plus to $ns, if yes
    } else {
      $s = $s + (int) $info[0][5];                     // plus to $s, if no
    }

    unset($info);
  }
}

var_dump($ns, $s); // int(29) int(18)
```

Version 2. Do away with one level in $info as mentioned earlier:

```
foreach(explode("\n",$in_data) as $line){
  $info = explode("    ", $line);
  if(in_array($info[4], $fa)) {
    $ns = $ns + (int) $info[5];
  } else {
    $s = $s + (int) $info[5];
  }
}
```

Alternative version, regexp:

```
foreach(explode("\n",$in_data) as $line){
  $info = preg_split('/\s{4,}/', $line); // Split when 4 or more spaces
  if(in_array($info[3], $fa)) {
      $ns = $ns + (int) $info[4];
  } else {
      $s = $s + (int) $info[4];
  }
}
```

That way you don't get any "junk columns" :).

Edit: I think it was PHP 7.1 that introduced some more "strictness" regarding adding values of different types, strings + numbers that is. A notice is issued, "A non well formed numeric value encountered". But if the string is cast/converted as a number before summing PHP will accept it. Casting can be done by adding `(int)` in front of the string value. (Provided it contains an integer value, of course, otherwise it needs to be cast differently)

Comment: This code doesn't work as expected. It does not make array i can work with. Every next array element has it`s number incresed. 1st row 1-5, 2nd 6-10 and so on. But your previos version, when $info is without [] works almost as expected

Comment: @Serique You mean the first version? You're right, fixing.

Comment: Yis, also \n, not /n. In regexp variant is correct. I like regexp more, trying to use it. Im makes correct arrays, but does not sum values. Trying figure out why

Comment: Too much copy'n'paste. Thanks, correcting.

Comment: @Serique That's odd, in my testrun it does sum correctly.

Comment: Yea, interesting. Mine returns all 0 with regex and ```Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /test/testparser.php on line 88``` with second variant of your code :) Now need to figure out. I feel I am so close!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238767/discussion-between-torbjorn-stabo-and-serique).

Answer (score 0):

After parsing the lines of text with regex, you only need to iterate the matches and conditionally sum the groups.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cK0se))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
Type A    GZ 600    11.09.2021 12:00        OST    9
Type A    GZ 601    11.09.2021 13:20        ADS    1
Type A    GZ 602    11.09.2021 21:35        OCS    1
Type A    GZ 603    11.09.2021 14:50        CSE    10
Type B    GZ 600    11.09.2021 12:00        OST    5
Type B    GZ 601    11.09.2021 13:20        ADS    3
Type B    GZ 602    11.09.2021 21:35        OCS    6
Type B    GZ 603    11.09.2021 14:50        CSE    12
TEXT;

$fa = ["OCS", "CSE"];
$result = ['s' => 0, 'ns' => 0, 'bs' => 0];

preg_match_all(
    '/^Type ([AB]).+([A-Z]{3})\h+(\d+)$/m',
    $text,
    $matches,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
foreach ($matches as $m) {
    if ($m[1] === 'B') {
        $result['bs'] += $m[3];
    } elseif (in_array($m[2], $fa)) {
        $result['s'] += $m[3];
    } else {
        $result['ns'] += $m[3];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  's' => 11,
  'ns' => 10,
  'bs' => 26,
)
```